# Building AMI with imds v2 enabled from packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

Trying to enable imds v2 for the AMI built by Packer, as per Hashicorp website, there is a attribute for imds named "imds_support = v2.0" but if I add imds_support, packer build fails.

```
source "amazon-ebs" "ubuntu-builder-1" {
  ami_name        = "ubuntu-AMI-2023-04-24T06-01-48Z"
  skip_create_ami = false
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  communicator    = "ssh"
  region          = "us-east-1"
  subnet_id       = "subnet-99999"
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                = "EC2-Ubuntu18.04-*"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"

    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["22222"]
  }
  ami_regions = []
  ami_users   = []
  winrm_username                        = "Administrator"
  ssh_username                          = "ubuntu"
  imds_support                          = "v2.0"
  aws_polling {
    delay_seconds = 120
    max_attempts  = 60
  }
  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint               = "enabled"
    http_put_response_hop_limit = "1"
    http_tokens                 = "required"
  }
  force_deregister      = false
  force_delete_snapshot = false
  iam_instance_profile = "AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup"

}
```

Error message when we do code build - *An argument named "imds_support" is not expected here*

Referred packer document - https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs#imds_support

Comment: What packer version are you using?

Comment: packer --version
1.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for `imds` in EBS in the Packer Amazon plugin was [added in version 1.2.2](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-amazon/releases/tag/v1.2.2). You would need to ensure your installed version of the plugin is at least at that version:

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      version = ">= 1.2.2" # preferably "~> 1.2.0" for latest patch version
      source = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
    }
  }
}
```